# Is Stellar Laboratory broken? only shows my XLM balance, not my USD balance (logging in with ledger nano)

Tags: stellar-laboratory, ledger-nano

Ugh. I have 900,000 USD on GCT62JTWDK2AZ4EUHWJKUBAXAHQANPNEKRB6JW555WR2J2EQVFIJYV3Q   and stellar lab https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/dashboard only shows the XLM balance.

I tried to send USD to GCGSZ4RAZS7I7BVKKVRUBJNS5ZMXH5GZNBKA7P5BUD7Q3SZGOESROAEM which has trustline to USD and it will only allow sending of XLM.

[image: stllar lab screen]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't stellar lab. It is "account viewer" which ONLY works with XLM assets.

you can use Stellar Laboratory to construct a payment or StellarX.